# Store DatastoreKey object over string as reference profit?

Tags: google-cloud-datastore

Is there any advantages for storing DatastoreKeys over ordinary strings in entity's property?

Let's say we have this entity:

```
{ 
    someForeignKey: DatastoreKey
}
```

That has only field of type DatastoreKey.
Will there be any difference if I'll store just a simple string of the key, In case if we consider that there are no namespaces used, or strings are referencing entities in a namespace scope only?

```
{
    someForeignKey: string
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A datastore key isn't just a string, it's actually a list of pairs of key kinds and key identifiers describing the entire entity ancestry of the foreign key. Yes, it can be represented as a single string (at least some client libraries have a method to obtain a corresponding urlsafe string, for example).

The advantages I see for storing the key would be:

- it includes the key type checking (but note that the entity for the key doesn't actually have to exist), which can't done for a string
- it can be used as-is to access the foreign entity, a string would have to be converted back to a key to do that

The namespaces don't really have any significance in this context.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to [Dan Cornilescu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4495081/dan-cornilescu) comments, I copy below the [official documentation key description](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/entities):

> Each entity in Cloud Datastore has a key that uniquely identifies it.
>   The key consists of the following components:
>
> - The namespace of the entity, which allows for [multitenancy](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/multitenancy).
> - The [kind](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/entities#kinds_and_identifiers) of the entity, which categorizes it for the purpose of Cloud    Datastore queries.
> - An [identifier](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/entities#kinds_and_identifiers) for the individual entity, which can be either:
>
>   - a key name string.
>   - an integer numeric ID.
> - An optional [ancestor path](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/entities#ancestor_paths) locating the entity within the Cloud Datastore hierarchy.
>
> An application can fetch an individual entity from Cloud Datastore
>   using the entity's key, or it can retrieve one or more entities by
>   issuing a [query](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/queries) based on the entities' keys or property values.